PHPStan / @return all possible children that extend specific class
I have a problem with @return types. It seems that either it's a bug in PHPStan or I'm doing something wrong.
Error:
abstract class Aclass {}
final class Bclass extends Aclass {}
final class Cclass extends Aclass {}

final class Factory {
    /**
     * @template T of Aclass
     * @param class-string<T> $param
     * @return T
     */
    public function create($param) {
        // some kind of factory logic
        return new Bclass();
    }
}

No error:
abstract class Aclass {}
final class Bclass extends Aclass {}
final class Cclass extends Aclass {}

final class Factory {
    /**
     * @template T of Aclass
     * @param class-string<T> $param
     * @return Aclass
     */
    public function create($param) {
        // some kind of factory logic
        return new Bclass();
    }
}

Why does PHPStan give me an error? Isn't @template T of Aclass + @return T the same as @return Aclass?
I'm expecting no errors.

T of Aclass means that T is either Aclass or an inherited class.
So, in this case:
final class Factory {
    /**
     * @template T of Aclass
     * @param class-string<T> $param
     * @return T
     */
    public function create($param) {
        // some kind of factory logic
        return new Bclass();
    }
}

T may be Cclass. But the method returns an instance of Bclass, which does not extend Cclass, hence the error.
This code gives no error:
final class Factory {
    /**
     * @template T of Aclass
     * @param class-string<T> $param
     * @return T
     */
    public function create($param) {
        // some kind of factory logic
        return new $param();
    }
}


Unfortunately return new $param(); is not working for me because of different naming constructors.
public function create($param) {
// some kind of factory logic
if ($condition1) {
return Bclass::createOne();
} elseif ($condition2) {
return Bclass::createTwo();
} elseif ($condition3) {
return Cclass::createThree();
}
// etc.
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid class name');
}

